# How can I make a `weeks_ago` helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make a helper that will tell me how many weeks ago (rounded down) with rails? It could be based of the `time_ago_in_words` helper however I'd want it to return: "last week" then afterwards just `two weeks ago`, `three weeks ago`, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def my_time_ago_in_words(from_time, include_seconds = false)
  to_time   = Time.now
  weeks_ago = ((to_time - from_time)/1.week).abs
  [nil, "last week", "two weeks ago", "three weeks ago"][weeks_ago] || 
      distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time, include_seconds)
end
```

This function will behave the same as `time_ago_in_words`. When the `from_time` is between 1 - 3 week ago, this will print `last week`, `two weeks ago`, `three weeks ago` otherwise it will print the usual.

Comment: I'd recommend the name `weeks_ago_in_words`, as it is more descriptive of the method's actual content.

Comment: This function is really a patch to `time_ago_in_words` as it preserves the existing functionality of the function. Correct approach is to patch the `time_ago_in_words` probably using `alias_method_chain`.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a nice patch to distance_of_time_in_words:

http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4cbb9db0a5ff65b0a626a5b043331abefd89e717/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L68-103

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can write custom time descriptions for the other levels (day, month, year).

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/392707640/the-more-you-know-custom-time-descriptions